# 'NSSet?' does not contain a member called 'Generator'

Tags: ios, swift, nsset

I am overriding the hit test behaviour of a view.

```
 override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView?
    {
        var touches:NSSet? = event?.allTouches()
        for touch in touches
        {
            //look at each touch
        }
    }
```

I need to check if the touchphase is began. However I cannot seem to iterate through all the touches.

I get the error

```
'NSSet?' does not contain a member called 'Generator'
```

I am assuming this means I cannot iterate an NSSet like I would an array?

Do you know the proper syntax in Swift to iterate an NSSet?

Comment: Do you need to unwrap your optional? Try `for touch in touches?`

Comment: Yup just tried it works

Comment: i love me some optionals :-|

Comment: A question mark (as in `NSSet?`) in the error message is usually relevant!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to iterate on an optional set. You'll need to unwrap it first.

Comment: Really surprised this slipped past me!

Answer (score 2):

`allTouches` returns an optional `NSSet`, so it must be unwrapped first - I suggest using optional binding as follows:

```
    if let touches = event?.allTouches() {
        for touch in touches
        {
            //look at each touch
        }
    }
```